# jquery change href and open new window

Tags: jquery, ajax

I need to change href in anchor and then open link in new window, but this code doesn't work. Any ideas? Obviously the url returned from the ajax call is correct.

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">alink</a>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('a').on('click', function(e){
         e.preventDefault(); 
         _this = $(this);
         $.ajax({ type:"GET", url:A_URL, dataType:"json",
               success: function(data){                                     
                        var u = data.results[0].trackViewUrl;
                        _this.attr('href', u);                              
                        window.open(u, '_blank');               
               }            
        })
    })

})
```

Comment: What exactly is "not working"? Also, what is `A_URL`

Comment: I think A_URL is "a url" :D some url.

Comment: Try to add some semicolon behind your brackets.

Comment: Sorry. As Shogun says A_URL is an url and the problem is that no new window opens

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you want change only url and open in new window:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('a').on('click', function (e) {
        $(this).attr("href", "new Url");
        $(this).attr("target", "_blank");
    })
})
```

but if you want get new url by ajax:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('a').on('click', function (e) {
        var $this = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            url: 'GetUrl',
            async: false,
            success: function (url) {
                $this.attr("href", url);
                $this.attr("target", "_blank");
            },
            error: function () {
                e.preventDefault();
            }
        });
    })

})
```

Comment: Works on my machine is not an answer. Which problem did you solve?

Comment: @Bart Riemens I believe his idea was to show the workflow is definitely not an issue, so it must be local to a variable he's not correctly identifying.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$('a').on('click', function(e){
     e.preventDefault(); 
     var me = $(this);

     $.get(
         A_URL,
         {},
         function(data) {
              var u = data.results[0].trackViewUrl;
              me.attr('href', u);                              
              window.open(u, '_blank');      
         },
         'JSON'

     );
})
```

Comment: As written [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) $.get() is a shorthand Ajax function, so your code is equivalent to mine.